# Input suggestionItems disappear

Tags: sapui5

On the input control, I enabled suggestion. 
The definition looks as follow:

```
<Input id="ins-add-plant"
    showSuggestion="true"
    value="{vmNewItem>/sPlant}"
    placeholder="{i18n>insColPlant}"
    maxLength="{vmNewItemMetaModel>/oPlantProp/maxLength}"
    suggestionItems="{vmPlantProposal>/aPlants}">
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{vmPlantProposal>Plant}"/>
        <core:Item text="{vmPlantProposal>Name}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData linebreak="true"/>
    </layoutData>
</Input>
```

The problem is, the suggestion does not appear but when I just have one `suggestionItem`, like:

```
<Input id="ins-add-plant"
    showSuggestion="true"
    value="{vmNewItem>/sPlant}"
    placeholder="{i18n>insColPlant}"
    maxLength="{vmNewItemMetaModel>/oPlantProp/maxLength}"
    suggestionItems="{vmPlantProposal>/aPlants}">
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{vmPlantProposal>Plant} {vmPlantProposal>Name}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData linebreak="true"/>
    </layoutData>
</Input>
```

Then it works as expected.

Why it does not work, when I have more then one `suggestionItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding an [aggregation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation) uses exactly one template which is repeated for each item. That is why your second example works and the first one not.

There are controls, e.g. List, supporting aggregations with complex content, but the Input control supports only `sap.ui.core.Item` or `sap.ui.core.ListItem` for the aggregation `suggestionItems`.